# Setting Facebook Cover Photo via API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, profile

Is there a way to get and set the new cover photo on the Facebook timeline profile via the API?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There´s no API support for changing user profile cover, but you can upload a photo and then redirect user to:
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=PHOTO_ID

Comment: This does not appear to work anymore (at least on the Facebook with the new Graph Search enabled).

Comment: @derekaug It's still working. All you need is to get a User picture ID and replace it for preview_cover parameter. The picture needs to be already on user profile.

Comment: Confirmed. This is still working!

Answer (score 17):

There is an API for updating the cover photo on a page

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

It asks for a photo id which I guess is the id of a photo from the users album. I am trying to update the photo, though think that first need to update that photo in album to retrieve the photo id

Comment: This is very cool, but doesn't seem to work for profiles. I upload a photo and user the id as the value for cover.

FOr a regular user, it returns
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Can only call this method on valid test users for your app","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

For a test user it returns true, but the cover photo doesn't change.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the picture via the regular photo APIs (it's in the 'Cover Photos' album) and also in the `cover` field of the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) - a sample call being `/me?fields=cover` to retrieve it.

There's no API to set the User cover photo and I'm not aware of any plans to add one.

Pages' cover photos can be edited using the API - see the [Pages API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) for more information - you make a POST request to `/PAGE_ID?cover=<ID of a photo in the page's album>` with the Page access token

Comment: Hi lgy, i try this one. but unfortunately it showing an error {"error": {"message":"(#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page","type": "OAuthException","code": 200}}. i am the admin of my page

Answer (score 1):

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if($user_id == 0 || $user_id == "")
{
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'redirect_uri'         => 'http://yoursite.com/upload.php?coverid='xxxxxx',
    'scope'      => "publish_stream,user_photos,user_photo_video_tags,user_videos"));

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$login_url';</script>";
    exit();
}

//get profile album
$albums = $facebook->api("/me/albums");
$album_id = ""; 
foreach($albums["data"] as $item){
    if($item["type"] == "cover_photo"){
        $album_id = $item["id"];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: From my experience, the type of the cover photo album is `"cover"` and not `"cover_photo"`. I am also able to get that ID in JavaScript. However, so far no luck in updating the current cover photo...