# PHP - Possible to automatically change MY profile pciture? Cover Photo?

Tags: php, facebook, profile, image

Curious if the PHP Facebook SDK allows me to change only my own profile picture and cover photo. From the reading I've done I'm thinking no, but I wasn't able to find any recent, direct articles.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't actually change it, but you can get half way!

[Setting Facebook Cover Photo via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849783/setting-facebook-cover-photo-via-api)

"There´s no API support for changing user profile cover, but you can upload a photo and then redirect user to: http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=PHOTO_ID"