# How to update the profile cover photo using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

There is an API support to update the cover photos for pages. Can I change my timeline cover photo using Facebook Graph API? There is a similar question in stack overflow [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849783/setting-facebook-cover-photo-via-api).
I have tried every solution in this question but I an unable to change the cover photo. I have used the method to update the page cover photo [click here to see the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) and this is the error

`Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#10) Application does not have permission for this action`

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Setting Facebook Cover Photo via API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849783/setting-facebook-cover-photo-via-api) where [the answer has been given](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7849839/1515819).

Comment: Read the question completely before making a comment. I have mentioned that link and clearly stated that I have tried all the answers mentioned in that question but its not working.

Comment: What is not working? Not all answers are good to take. You **can't** change the cover of a **profile** through the API.

Comment: That question was asked couple of years before. I thought Facebook might have added a feature for it. There are other answers which I have tried and it is not working

Comment: No, it didn't change. To answer your question, [the Page doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) still has a  _Setting a Cover Photo_ paragraph whereas [the User doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) still doesn't, which matches perfectly with what has been said in 2011.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After recent changes to Facebook api, we can only make cover photo of a page with photos which are in an album. We have to create an album and upload the photo to that album then we can use that photo as cover photo. Previously we can make cover from "photos of page's" album.

```
$args = array('name' => 'awesome album name', 'message' => 'awesome album message');
try {
    $album_id =$facebook->api("/$page_id/albums", 'post', $args);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$args = array('image' =>'@'.realpath('/var/www/facebook.png'));
try{
    $uploaded_photo_details = $facebook->api("/{$album_id['id']}/photos", 'post', $args);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($uploaded_photo_details['id'])){
$args = array('cover' => $uploaded_photo_details['id'], 'offset_y' =>0);
try {
    $cover_details = $facebook->api("/{$page_id}", 'post', $args);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I wrote a complete tutorial about this http://blog.jambura.com/2012/12/05/change-facebook-pages-cover-photo-using-graph-api-and-page-api/

Comment: You are a rockstar Zakir!

Comment: How can we set cron job on this?

Comment: code is the same, all you have to do include the lib files like The include file is at /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/protected/config.php